File 'src\main.ts' is missing from the TypeScript compilation in Angular 18
i recently got this weird issue when using the ng serve command :
Application bundle generation failed. [1.788 seconds]

X [ERROR] File 'src\main.ts' is missing from the TypeScript compilation. [plugin angular-compiler]

  Ensure the file is part of the TypeScript program via the 'files' or 'include' property.

However, when I check the tsconfig.app.json I can see that the file main.ts is indeed included :
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/main.ts"
  ]
}


I checked on the internet for solution to this problem but none of them worked.
I'm using Angular 18.0.6 by the way.
Thank you very much

fwiw, the default config, doesn't have it in the include section.
